# Python Telebot (PyTelegramBotAPI)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

'''Я начинающий'''
Хочу написать бота для анкет (приятная версия гугл формы - идейно).

Есть более или менее работающий код, однако, он считывает данные телеграмм аккаунта (имя, фамилия).
**В чем нужна помощь**: Как научить его принимать введенное имя, и уже после запускать часть с выбором из меню?

На данный момент, после ввода имени выходит сообщение "*Рад знакомству с тобой (введенное имя)*". Затем выходит меню, но после выбора пункта бот присылает : "*Рад знакомству с тобой (опросник/помощь/итд)*". Буду искренне рад любой помощи и подсказкам в целом по изучению написания ботов, спасибо!

```
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('токен')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    send_mess = f"<b>Привет, я твой личный помощник</b>!\n What's your name?"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_mess, parse_mode='html')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    grt = 'Рад знакомству с тобой'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, grt + ' ' + message.text)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def mess(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Опросники')
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Помощь')
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Плюшки')
    btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Фидбек')
    btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('FAQ')
    markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5)
    send_mess = f"<b>Выбери подходящий вариант</b>"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_mess, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def mess(message):
    get_message_bot = message.text.strip().lower()

    if get_message_bot == "начать тест заново":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Опросники')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Помощь')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Плюшки')
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Фидбек')
        btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('FAQ')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5)
        final_message = "Решил попробовать что-то ещё? \nВыбери какое направление тебя интересует:"

    elif get_message_bot == "опросники":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('1')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('2')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
        final_message = "текст"
    else:
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Опросники')
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Помощь')
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Плюшки')
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Фидбек')
        btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('FAQ')
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5)
        final_message = "Так, так, так\nПостой, лучше нажми на одну из интерактивных кнопок ниже"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, final_message, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: первый `message_handler(content_types=['text']` будет работать раньше нижних. какой бы текст ты не отправлял оно будет срабатывать и не оставлять нижний. Этому вопросу уже несколько лет, почему он в находится главном StackOverflow ?

Answer (score 0):

Я бы немного переделал ваш код, таким образом:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('Опросники')
btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('Помощь')
btn3 = types.KeyboardButton('Плюшки')
btn4 = types.KeyboardButton('Фидбек')
btn5 = types.KeyboardButton('FAQ')
markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5)

markup2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=3)
btn1 = types.KeyboardButton('1')
btn2 = types.KeyboardButton('2')
markup2.add(btn1, btn2)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    username = message.from_user.username
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  "Let`s start!", reply_markup=markup)
    send_mess = f"Привет, {username}! Я твой личный помощник!"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_mess, reply_markup=markup)



def mess(message):
    send_mess = "Выбери подходящий вариант"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_mess, reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text =='начать тест заново')
def foo(message):
    final_message = "Решил попробовать что-то ещё? \nВыбери какое направление тебя интересует:"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, final_message, reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text =="Опросники")
def foo(message):
    final_message = "текст"
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, final_message, parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup2)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, однако, проблема все также осталась. Т.е. он все также считывает слова после отправки имени. 
Рез-т пример: 
- Имя
- Рад знакомству с тобой (Имя)
- Опросники
- Рад знакомству с тобой Опросники

Comment: тогда могу предложить вам следующее(я изменил свой ответ)

Comment: Убери токен из сообщения, а лучше вообще удали. Я уже побаловался если честно, но ничего серьезного)))

Comment: @MaHryCT спасибо, но всё равно это старый токен)

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю так:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')

btn = ['Опросники', 'Помощь', 'Плюшки', 'Фидбек', 'FAQ']
btn_list = [types.KeyboardButton(text=x) for x in btn]

name = ''

answer_list = [1, 2, 3]

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  "Let`s start!")
    send_mess = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите имя:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send_mess, name)

def name(message):
    global name
    button = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    button.add(*btn_list)
    name = message.text
    send_mess = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Привет {name}\nВыбери раздел:', reply_markup=button)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(send_mess, cat)

def cat(message):
    if message.text in btn:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я понял')
    else:
        send_mess = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Я не понял')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(send_mess, cat)

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]